# How to update model async in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nativescript

I have the following function that should hide the element for connecting to Facebook if connection is successful. I create two functions, success and error, that fire off after Firebase correctly logs in the user. I know these two functions hit because I have been able to debug them and see the console.log statements within on the console after each has fired. But the element when Facebook connection is successful does not hide. If I look at the properties of `this`, then `isFacebookConnected` and `isGoogleConnected` don't show up but `User` and `Providers` properties do.

Is there something I'm misunderstanding about how to pass in the current model reference to a function so that it can modify the state of the UI? How can I get the UI element to hide on success?

`FacebookAuthenticator.ts`

```
import { firebase } from '../../app';
import { IAuthenticator } from './IAuthenticator';
import { Navigator } from '../navigation/Navigator';

export class FacebookAuthenticator implements IAuthenticator  {
    public successFunction: Function;
    public errorFunction: Function;

    constructor(success: Function, error: Function) {
        this.successFunction = success;
        this.errorFunction = error;
    }

    public authenticate() {
        const successFunction = this.successFunction;
        const errorFunction = this.errorFunction;

        firebase.login({
            type: firebase.LoginType.FACEBOOK
        }).then(
            function (result) {
                successFunction(result);
            },
            function (errorMessage) {
                errorFunction(errorMessage);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

`AccountViewModel.ts`

```
export class AccountViewModel extends Observable {
    public appVersion : string;
    public User : User;
    public isFacebookConnected : boolean;
    public isGoogleConnected : boolean;
    private authenticator : IAuthenticator;
    private providers : Array<Provider>;

    constructor() {
        super();

        appVersion.getVersionName().then((result) => {
            this.notifyPropertyChange("appVersion", "Version " + result);
        });

        firebase.getCurrentUser().then((result) => {
            this.User = result;
            this.notifyPropertyChange("User", this.User);
            this.providers = ProviderParser.getUserProviders(this.User);
            this.setProviderConnectivty();
        });
    }

    public setFacebookSwitch(togglingOn : boolean) {
        const successFunction : Function = (model : AccountViewModel) => {
            return () => {
                model.isFacebookConnected = true;
                model.notifyPropertyChange("isFacebookConnected", model.isFacebookConnected);
            }
        };

        const errorFunction : Function = (model : AccountViewModel) => {
            return () => {
                model.isFacebookConnected = false;
                model.notifyPropertyChange("isFacebookConnected", model.isFacebookConnected);
                dialogs.alert({
                    title: "Unexpected Error",
                    message: "An unexpected error occurred during login. Please contact the developer.",
                    okButtonText: "Ok"
                });
            }
        };

        this.authenticator = new FacebookAuthenticator(successFunction(this), errorFunction(this));

        if (togglingOn && this.providers.indexOf(Provider.Facebook) === -1) {
            this.authenticator.authenticate();
        }
    }
}
```

`Account.xml`

```
<StackLayout row="2" column="0" class="preferenceGroup">
            <Label text="Connected Accounts" class="preferenceGroupHeading"/>
            <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*, auto" visibility="{{ isFacebookConnected ? 'collapsed' : 'visible' }}">
                <Label row="0" column="0" text="Facebook" class="preferenceItem"/>
                <Label row="0" column="0" 
                        text="Repeat accesses your public profile, friend list, and email address" 
                        textWrap="true"
                        horizontalAlignment="left"
                        class="preferenceSubText"/>
                <Switch loaded="facebookSwitchLoaded" />
            </GridLayout>
            <Label class="divider" />
            <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*, auto">
                <Label row="0" column="0" text="Google" class="preferenceItem"/>
                <Label row="0" column="0" 
                        text="Repeat accesses your public profile, friend list, and email address" 
                        textWrap="true"
                        horizontalAlignment="left"
                        class="preferenceSubText"/>
                <Switch checked="{{isGoogleConnected}}"/>
            </GridLayout>
        </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `model` is not referencing the actual model you're working with. The current object should be `this` in the closure.

Try modifying your code like this and see if it works:

```
public setFacebookSwitch(togglingOn : boolean) {
        const successFunction : Function = (model : AccountViewModel) => {
            return () => {
                this.isFacebookConnected = true;
```

If that doesn't work (in case the Function is overriding this context), try to store `this` in a temp var first:

```
public setFacebookSwitch(togglingOn : boolean) {
        const myTempThis = this;
        const successFunction : Function = (model : AccountViewModel) => {
            return () => {
                myTempThis.isFacebookConnected = true;
```

Comment: Thank you. The issue was the context so the second answer of yours worked; albeit with a bit of delay on the UI side. This would mean that I don't really need the (model : AccountViewModel) parameter and I should just be able to call it normally. I really need to look more into contexts because I thought by using (model:AccountViewModel) and calling with successFunction(this) I would be able to retain the context. Why doesn't it work like that? Do you have a resource on this I can look at? I was looking at this too: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript

Comment: Happy that it worked. That knowledge comes more from JavaScript than TypeScript, I don't have a specific resource but would recommend googling something like `this in javascript tutorial`. Also have a look at closures (which is why the 2nd example works).